# iPad SplitViewController with separate navigation stack for detail view

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm hoping someone can tell me if it's possible to put a separate navigation stack on the detail view for a split view controller. I've been banging my head against this problem for a while and now am wondering if it's even possible.

I'm developing a universal application that allows users to browse a conference schedule.  On the iphone this is simply a a table view where users:

-->selects a session topic from a list of topics (plain table)

---->selects a session title from a list of topics(plain table)

------>sees details about the session including papers to be presented and can selected a individual table (grouped table)

-------->sees details about the paper (grouped table)

What I'd like to do for the ipad version is something like this:
-->selects a session topic from a list of topics (root controller, plain table)

---->selects a session title from a list of topics(root controller, plain table)

------>sees details about the session including papers to be presented and can selected a individual table (detail controller, grouped table)

-------->sees details about the paper (detail controller, grouped table)

That's the goal, but everything I've tried in terms of getting the detail controller to have a separate navigation stack has screwed up the split view controller. I can get everything up to the last step working fine.  But as soon as I push a the details about the paper onto the detail controller stack, the splitview controller goes crazy.

Has anyone accomplished something like what I'm describing above?

I could simply replace the session details controller with the papers detail controller instead of trying to push it onto the stack.  But then I lose all the benefits of the nav stack, lose all the free transition animations, and have to maintain a substantially altered version of the same table for the iPhone and iPad.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I swear, sometimes I think stack overflows greatest benefit is how often publicly posting a problem spurs me to solve it myself.

So what I describe is definitely possible.  Simply look at the settings app.  It does exactly what I describe.

The problem I had was that some of my detail view controllers, because they were inherietend from the iPhone version, did not implement "shouldAutoRotate".  Once I added that, everything fell into place.

If anyone else if facing a similar problem, I might also suggest you start with Matt Long's walkthrough of adding a navigation stack to the splitViewController here:http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/24/fixing-the-uisplitviewcontroller-template/